# Android startActivityForResult pass text + images

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have a problem, when the user type something in the edit text, and then press the button which triggers startActivityForResult (linked image) to let the user choose a picture, but after onActivityResult, the typed edit text disappears. How can I save the edit text and put it into the intent before startActivityForResult , if I set intentAction = ACTION_GET_CONTENT and type "image/jpeg" ?

[StartActivityForResult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8NCy.png)

[onActivityResult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swyF7.png)

Comment: how do you want use the content of edit text?

Comment: I would like to set the the text of the editText typed by the user before he presses the button to uploadImage